# Complex numbers - addition of two modulus help

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Ok, so I got the answer to part i), but however, I'm not so sure how to get the answer to part ii). The answers say its an ellipse and they specified the equation, but I can't understand how they came to that conclusion. Can anyone help me out, please :)
[image: help]

Answer (score 0):

If you remember the geometric definition of an ellipse, then you can see right away that that's what part ii describes.

Definition: An ellipse is the set of all points for which the sum of the distances from two fixed points is constant.

In this case, we want the sum of the distance from A and the distance from B to equal 12.

Comment: ok then, but then how do i get the equation of ellipse?

Comment: @betty_carr The given equation in $z$ ***is*** the equation of the ellipse. Are you looking for the cartesian equation or what?

Comment: @betty_carr Try setting $z = x + iy$ and working the algebra...